# Change the output format of zsh's time

Tags: time, zsh

I've just switched to `zsh`.  However, I really don't like how the `time` builtin command also outputs the command that it's timing.  I much prefer the `bash` style output. Anyone know how to switch it over?

Zsh:

```
[casqa1:~/temp]$ time grep foo /dev/null
/usr/local/gnu/bin/grep --color -i foo /dev/null  0.00s user 0.00s system 53% cpu 0.004 total
```

Bash:

```
[casqa1:~/temp]$ bash
casqa1.nyc:~/temp> time grep foo /dev/null

real        0.0
user        0.0
sys         0.0
```

Thanks,

/YGA

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is fairly close:

```
$ TIMEFMT=$'\nreal\t%*E\nuser\t%*U\nsys\t%*S'

$ time sleep 1

real    1.01s
user    0.00s
sys     0.00s
```

Comment: My proposed edit was rejected 2-1. Ideally, the format should be `TIMEFMT=$'\nreal\t%*E\nuser\t%*U\nsys\t%*S'`. The `*`s in the flags formats them as hours/minutes as per bash, instead of just seconds. More information on `TIMEFMT` [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-TIMEFMT).

Comment: I'm trying to get colours with something like:  `export TIMEFMT="%J  \033[1;32m%U\033[0m user \e[1;32m%S\e[0m system \e[1;32m%P\e[0m cpu \e[1;32m%*E\e[0m total"`,  but it is just printing the raw string instead of colours.  Is this possible?

Comment: Use a "C-quoted string": `TIMEFMT=$'%J  \033[1;32m%U\033[0m user \e[1;32m%S\e[0m system \e[1;32m%P\e[0m cpu \e[1;32m%*E\e[0m total'` (do you really need to export it?). Cool idea, btw!

Comment: @Sparhawk: I changed my answer to use your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to disable the builtin command and use the time binary provided by your operating system.
I have the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
disable -r time       # disable shell reserved word
alias time='time -p ' # -p for POSIX output
```

This way time outputs to STDERR.

Answer (score 5):

Just a small precision regarding Dennis Williamson's very useful answer (the "fairly close" part): bash's built-in `time` outputs to `stderr`, while zsh's outputs to `stdout`.

This command can illustrate the difference: `time (echo abc) 2>/dev/null`

In bash, it outputs:

```
    $ time (echo abc) 2>/dev/null
    abc
```

In zsh, with the suggested TIMEFMT variable:

```
    $ time (echo abc) 2>/dev/null
    abc

    real    0.00s
    user    0.00s
    sys     0.00s
```