# Get the same bash time command format of MacOS in zsh on Debian 10 Buster

Tags: macos, bash, debian, zsh, time

From the following link [change format for time command](https://superuser.com/questions/71857/change-the-output-format-of-zshs-time), I would like to get exactly the same format of MacOS Catalina `time` command present in `bash` into zsh of Debian 10 Buster.

So, I tested the solution given on this link :

```
$ export TIMEFMT=$'\nreal\t%E\nuser\t%U\nsys\t%S'
```

and if do a : `$ time sleep 63`

I get :

```
real    63.00s
user    0.00s
sys     0.00s
```

whereas into bash of MacOS Catalina, I have with the same command :

```
real    1m3.030s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.014s
```

I mean, on Debian, elapsed time doesn't display the minutes it is over 60 seconds. It always displays only the seconds. Moreover, if lower than `60s`, we keep the `Om0.004s`, i.e  `Om` in front of seconds

How to fix this to have the same format on Debian 10 zsh than MacOS bash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote from the section `TIMEFMT` of `man zshparam`:

> A star may be inserted between the percent sign and flags printing time (e.g., `%*E`); this  causes  the
>                 time  to  be printed in `hh:mm:ss.ttt` format (hours and minutes are only printed if they are not zero).
>                 Alternatively, `m` or `u` may be used (e.g., `%mE`) to produce time output in milliseconds or  microseconds, respectively.

So, while it's not exactly the same format as in bash, with

```
export TIMEFMT=$'\nreal\t%*E\nuser\t%*U\nsys\t%*S'
```

you'll get at least the minutes and hours separated:

```
$ time sleep 63

real    1:03.00
user    0.000
sys     0.003
```